# Displaying SQL data without a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a page to display answers to questions posted to certain authorities. I've been successful in displaying the content (imported from a SQL table) in a table, but due to its nature, and for better readability, I'd like to display it in a different format, wherein each answer succeeds each question, as a paragraph, as you would write in a notebook. How can I change the code to do so? 
[image]

```
            <?php
                        $servername="localhost";
                        $username="root";
                        $password='';
                        $conn=mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());
                        $dbname = 'bsp';   
                        mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());
                        $sql = "SELECT query,answer FROM answers";
                        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
                     echo "<table>";
                    echo '<tr><th class="one">Query</th>
                        <th class="two">Answer</th>';

                echo "</tr>";
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    $query=$row["query"];
                    $answer=$row["answer"];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$query</td>
                           <td>$answer</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";        
                }
            echo "</table><br>";        
            ?>
```

Comment: You learn HTML / CSS and build the structure you want, we aren't going to do it for you.

Comment: I sense hostility in your comment.
I am well versed with HTML and CSS, but wasn't sure on how to implement this idea, which is why I asked for your help.
You're free to not answer. But please don't speak for the others.

Comment: Nothing hostile intended, and while you may indeed get your answer as shown below, it is not what SO is about, you're suppose to try and research before coming to SO. (Again, not trying to be hostile or rude, just trying to keep the quality of the site up).

Comment: I did try and research. That is precisely how I ended up with the tabular form. I'm self taught at this, and don't completely understand the nuances of the code I'm writing, yet. I am not one to post on SO frivolously, and do so only when I'm unable to find a suitable answer pertaining to my doubt in the first place. I appreciate, and share your demand for quality, but request you to entertain some of the less experienced like myself, till such time that we get better at this. 
Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

```php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<p><strong>$row['query']</strong><br>$row['answer']</p>";      
}
```